# Which part of my CSS is causing the text to disappear in mobile but show on a PC?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

When I view [www.Edge-Trainer.com](http://www.Edge-Trainer.com) in my browser I'm able to see the section of text that starts out as "Ready for positive changes in your life? We can help you get ready for 2017!" but when I view it on my cell phone, it's not there.

What change in the html or CSS would correct that?

Thanks in advance,

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Page width change. 
**Your HTML**

```
<article id="anything-slider">
<section id="slider-container">
    <div class="anythingSlider anythingSlider-default activeSlider" style="width: 440px; height: 340px;"><div class="anythingWindow" style="width: 440px; height: 340px;"><ul id="slides" class="anythingBase horizontal" style="width: 440px; left: 0px;">
        <li class="panel1 panel" style="width: 440px; height: 340px;">
            <section class="slide-elements" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <div class="slide-img-container no-shadow left"> <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                    <style>.embed-container { position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; height: 0; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; } .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; }</style><div class="embed-container"><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zddzPD7YABc?&amp;autoplay=0&amp;theme=light&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;modestbranding=0&amp;rel=0&amp;disablekb=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>


                </div>
                <div class="title">
                    <h1>Ready for positive changes in your life? We can help you get ready for 2017!</h1>
                    <p>Our private personal training studio is located in a convenient downtown Houston location. Contact us today to start achieving your body transformation <strong>goals</strong>.</p>
                </div>
                <p>The Edge Personal Training Studio has top personal trainers with the knowledge and abilities to help you achieve <strong>your goals</strong>. We're so confident in our personal training abilities we offer a 100% money back guarantee!</p>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul></div><span class="arrow back" style="display: none;"><a href="#"><span>«</span></a></span><span class="arrow forward" style="display: none;"><a href="#"><span>»</span></a></span></div>
</section>
```

your code inheritance #anything-slider > #slider-container ... .slide-elements > ... > .title

**Your CSS**

```
media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px)
anything-slider {    height: 340px;    padding-top: 0;} 
anything-slider {    padding: 30px 0 0;    height: 380px;    list-style: none;    overflow-y: auto;    overflow-x: hidden;    margin: 0 auto 30px;    position: relative;}
```

parent css is defined changing width but child css attriubte change do nothing.
so, title element seem like broken.

Answer (score 1):

Your anythingslider.css has a @media to handle smartphones screens on line 618 that hides a few elements. Including your title class.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know of an easy fix for that?